# Is it acceptable to retrofit a new-work plastic electrical box by screwing through it into a stud?

Tags: electrical

It is mechanically *possible* to install a standard new-work box in an existing wall by:

1. Cutting hole in drywall adjacent to a stud
2. Placing plastic box in the hole up against the stud
3. Screwing through the plastic into the stud. The screws would need to be somewhat angled and as much as possible positioned to penetrate the meat of the stud.

However, is this *acceptable* practice? To be clear, I'm asking about using a box that was not specifically designed to be mounted in this way.

Once concern I have is just that the screw heads could be slightly in the way, maybe a small risk of nicking wire insulation. But this is probably avoidable and there are plenty of other similar circumstances where that has to be taken into consideration.

Second concern would be if this violates electrical code for some reason? (USA)

---

Note - there are a few reasons you might prefer to use a new-work box instead of an old-work box (which would not require this procedure):

- Positioning
- You don't have one on hand
- Much more secure to attach to stud than to drywall, like for a large 240V plug

Comment: @FreeMan thank you for reading carefully... I edited to clarify I hope

Comment: @FreeMan and a second edit, why did I have to reread that 5 times before I saw my mistake? lol

Comment: Because it's much easier to note other people's mistakes than our own. :/

Comment: @FreeMan true words of wisdom :)

Comment: my ele does this all the time - not that this means it is code compliant but it doesn't get flagged on inspection.

Comment: I spent some time looking, but I can't find it now. Someone posted (in an answer) a pic of a new/old work box that has the screws driven at an angle through the side of the box (from the inside) and into the side of the stud. This is effectively what you're wanting to do, but in a makeshift way instead of a "designed from the factory" way. I presume that the box I saw was to code, so it's not inherently illegal, but I don't know if "make it up in the field" is legal or not. Good question, though.

Comment: [Found it!](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/11644/34147). Well, that's 8 years old, so maybe that's not _the_ question I was thinking of, but that's what I was thinking of.

Comment: @FreeMan that is exactly what I was describing, except as you noted using a box not expressly designed to be attached that way.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, as redlude97 mentions, they make boxes designed to mount this way.  They're often sold as old/new work boxes since they can be used just as easily either way.

Here's a picture of a typical example.  This one is made by Arlington and sold by [Platt](https://www.platt.com/platt-electric-supply/Switch-Outlet-Boxes-New-Old-Work/Arlington/F101/product.aspx?zpid=651477), (though this is not an endorsement of either of those companies; it just happened to be the first google result):

[image: Old/New Work Electrical Box]

Edit in response to your question edit:

Since you're asking specifically about using a new work box *not* designed for this purpose, that would most likely not be allowable unless the manufacturer specifically allows it in their instructions.  One of the primary jobs of electrical boxes is keeping contained any fires that may try to start inside of them, and UL (or other testing labs) make sure they do -- provided they're unmodified.  Once you start adding holes in them that the manufacturer didn't put there, then they can no longer guarantee their fire performance, and their UL listing is technically no longer valid.  Now, an inspector might not notice, and just assumed you used one of the ones designed to be mounted this way, but it would still be a code violation.  This falls under Sec. 110.3(B) of the electrical code -- you must follow manufacturers instructions when installing listed equiptment.

Comment: And why take any safety or liability risks?

Comment: Plus, boxes designed for old work are generally easier to handle in such situations.

Answer (score 3):

### Just use a metal box

You have much broader latitude to put additional holes in a metal box.

Just drill the holes that you require or prefer, fill them with screws, and you're all set.   Metal boxes are UL-listed on the presumption that none of the manufacturer-supplied screw holes will be filled.

Metal boxes do a much better job containing heat from arc faults, and they also assure breaker trip if a hot wire gets loose and contacts the box.  That is, after all, the purpose of a box.

Also, metal boxes provide several mechanisms for grounding switches and receps without having to run a ground wire to them.  Switches ground through the mounting screws, and receps also can do that if they are "self-grounding".

Comment: It is allowed to drill holes into metal boxes and mount them via screws from the inside of the box? Just want to confirm because this is NOT allowed for the plastic boxes (since it is "not used according to manufacturer instructions")

Comment: @divB yes, that's fine.  If you look at a plastic box, it is gusseted where the support structure is. That's because the plastic is too flimsy to accept a screw at any arbitrary location.  Steel boxes have a minimum thickness to ensure thread engagement of ground screws, and that makes them strong enough to stand on lol, let alone fasten anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

They make these boxes with preinstalled angled screws, without providing a product recommendation google smart box electrical 1 gang

Answer (score -1):

Making a hole in a box for a screw to mount it is acceptable.  If you look at this box from Carlon for example

https://new.abb.com/low-voltage/products/wire-cable-management/electrical-boxes/carlon-deep-blue

it can be used for both **old work** (cutting a hole and installing in an existing finished wall) or for **new work** (installing in the studs before the drywall or other wall finish is applied).

For new work, you'd be snapping off the flange used for new work - it's perforated so it will snap off easily.  Then you'd drill screws from inside the box into the stud.  As mentioned in the question, you would have to make sure you don't make a sharp burr inside the box - you wouldn't use a drywall screw or other flathead screw made to use in wood.

There is a practical limitation to consider thought.  Unless you have a right-angle adapter for your drill / driver

[image: right angle adapter]

driving screws inside the box is going to be a pain.  I'd recommend a screw with a pan head that will let you use a square or star drive - phillips would be less than ideal, and slotted would be an exercise in frustration.  I'd also recommend using a washer, so it's less likely to rip out of the plastic, and don't overtighten it.

The "smartbox" type boxes with the built-in angled screws inside

[image: Madison smartbox]

are more expensive, and have just a little less room inside for your wires and devices, but really easy to use, do not require a right-angle adapter, and easy to adjust the depth.  They still have ***way more room*** inside than the metal old-work style boxes, which are tiny - barely big enough to fit dimmers, smart switches, and GFCI devices.